# How to calculate the derivative of a random variable to one of the parameters?

Tags: random

So, I have a function: $f(x) = a\cdot x + b\cdot x + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, a+2b)$

I want to derive this function to one of the parameters (for example $a$) when performing a sensitivity analysis, but I get stuck with the epsilon part. Somebody has an idea?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: What is $N(0,a+2b)$?